# UITableView willDisplayCell not fired with an empty table

Tags: core-data, tableview

I'm using coredata and a `fetchedResultsController` to fill a `tableView`, cause the database is very large sometimes when I put a text in the searchbar it needs 4-5 seconds to show objects so I start a `spinner` and then stop it when search ends. I use the delegate method `willDisplayCell` as follows but when the search returns 0 objects spinner doesn't stop animating because `willDisplayCell` is not fired:

```
- (BOOL)isFinishedLoadingTableView:(UITableView *)tableView indexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSArray *visibleRows = [tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];   // did verify sorted ascending via logging
    NSIndexPath *lastVisibleCellIndexPath = [visibleRows lastObject];
    // For tableviews with multiple sections this will be more complicated.
    BOOL isPreviousCallForPreviousCell = self.previousDisplayedIndexPath.row + 1 == lastVisibleCellIndexPath.row;
    BOOL isLastCell = [indexPath isEqual:lastVisibleCellIndexPath];
    BOOL isFinishedLoadingTableView = isLastCell && ([tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0] == 1 || isPreviousCallForPreviousCell);
    self.previousDisplayedIndexPath = indexPath;
    return isFinishedLoadingTableView; }

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath
*)indexPath {
    BOOL isFinishedLoadingTableView = [self isFinishedLoadingTableView:tableView indexPath:indexPath];
    if (isFinishedLoadingTableView) {
        [activityIndicatorView stopAnimating];
    }
}
```

And here the FRC:

```
(NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"CivicoEntity" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSMutableArray *finalSearchTextArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSArray *tempSearchTextItems = [self.searchText componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

    for (NSString *string in tempSearchTextItems){
        if([string length]>0)
            [finalSearchTextArray addObject:string];
    }

    if (self.searchText) {
        NSMutableArray *predicatesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        for (NSString *string in finalSearchTextArray) {
            NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"indirizzo CONTAINS[cd] %@ OR toponimo CONTAINS[cd] %@", string, string];
            [predicatesArray addObject:predicate];
        }
        NSPredicate * finalPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicatesArray];
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:finalPredicate];
    }

    NSSortDescriptor *sort_indirizzo = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                              initWithKey:@"indirizzo" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    NSSortDescriptor *sort_civico = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                              initWithKey:@"civico" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sort_indirizzo, sort_civico, nil]];


    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
    [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                        managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                   cacheName:nil];
    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `willDisplayCell` method will get invoked when the `tableview` has to show at least one row/cell. This is your case, and you need to find some other solution to stop the spinner animation.

Try to insert the code:

```
[activityIndicatorView stopAnimating];
```

in the method:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

and inside that, check:

```
if (numberOfRows_to_return == 0) {
    [activityIndicatorView stopAnimating];
}
```

Comment: I tried but numberOfRowsInSection gets called also before fetch ends, so it returns 0 and then the real value after fetch. It seems that it is called before and after data is retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

I was intending to comment however did not have enough space...

If my understanding is correct, you have a number of options.

The mechanism you have developed works, but there are a few other ways to consider doing what is required. (Forgive me as I do not know your level of experience and skill with Objective-C.)

Firstly I would recommend doing some reading on how to optimize your `NSFetchedResultsController` (FRC). It may be that if you set a batch size in your FRC, data will populate more quickly and the spinner will not be necessary.

*I found these two books very helpful: from The Pragmatic Bookshelf – "Core Data, 2nd Edition, Data Storage and Management for iOS, OS X, and iCloud" (Jan 2013) by Marcus S. Zarra, and from Apress publishers – "Pro iOS Persistence Using Core Data", by Michael Privat and Robert Warner, note still in alpha.*

Secondly, how you filter the data for a search is important. You may be able to include a completion block in your filter method, that will stop animation once the method is complete.

As such, and this really is a comment but I did not have the room, I would ask that you provide a little more information. In particular information on your FRC and search mechanisms would be helpful.

Comment: I updated my question above with the FRC code. I use a batch size of 20 but DB is really large, 87.000 records and 30MB in size. I start fetching using a dispatch_async call where I do a performFetch and then I do [mytableview reloadData] with another async call on the main thread. Even if I try to count the fetchedResults objects it returns 0 before and then the right number of fetched objects. This behaviour always anticipates the stopanimating call inside willDisplayCell and the spinner stops few seconds before table is displayed.

Comment: I put an NSLog to count the fetchedObjects after performFetch and I saw that if I write a character a time in the searchbar it works, but I have to wait the table loading, if I write more characters at a time it returns 0 between typing them and then the correct value at the end, so the spinner stops animating immediately if I write more characters in the searchbar and I don't wait for the result between them....I suppose it depends by the dispatch async, because when I type a character it dispatches a thread to perform the fetch and before it ends it catches one more character and a new fetch

Comment: Before we consider using "Faulting" or "Prefetching" in your FRC, have you considered breaking your search text out of your FRC, to act as an independent filter for your FRC `fetchedObjects`?

Comment: by using `filteredArrayUsingPredicate` on your `fetchedObjects` within the `UISearchDisplayController` delegate method `searchDisplayController:shouldReloadTableForSearchString`?

Comment: What do you mean for "breaking you search text"? Now I tried to avoid search starts while typing, I force user to press the Search button, and it works, it's very fast. If search starts while typing it dispatch an async thread for every typed character and it makes it to return 0 for every character typed before the last one, or you had to wait it shows results between typing characters.

Comment: Apologies was not very clear... remove the search function from your FRC, invoke the `UISearchDisplayController` delegate method `shouldReloadTableForSearchString`, and place the search algorithm in that. In this way you can leave the FRC to the task of calling your data, and the above noted method to filter that data. By separating those tasks, you may find the UI is not blocked (frozen) so readily.

Comment: shouldReloadTableForSearchString now returns NO and searchBarSearchButtonClicked starts fetching, and it's really fast, but everytime I cancel the search and hide the searchBar it needs to reload and alphabetically sort the whole database (3-4 seconds) because after searching the FRC contains just the filtered records. If I put the search algorithm in the delegate it would always work on the FRC and I had the same problem when I want to hide the searchBar, so a full database reload was needed, or maybe I miss a diffent way...

Comment: I read also the above comment, but if If I work on the fetchedobjects array I miss changes when I go back and close searchBar, for example if I filer rhe fetchedobjects array and select on of those rows I edit something about that object, I save the context and go back. When I hide the searchBar If I don't make a new fetch I miss changes because the context was saved but the FRC did't get updated.